# How to change inactive color tabs bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change inactive tabs , but how ?
my code below :

css

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus, .nav-pills > li > a:hover {
background-color: #F47321 !important;
border-color: #FFFFFF !important;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: So what is problem you face. Please specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is for changing the color for active tabs and on hover of tags.

Please find the codes below for changing the color for active and inactive tabs both. Feel free to ask for any doubt.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Tabs</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    /*   Change Color for Active Tabs     */
    .nav-pills>li.active>a,
    .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,
    .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover,
    .nav-pills>li>a:hover,
    .nav>li>a:hover {
      background-color: #F47321;
      border-color: #FFFFFF;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    /*   Change Color for Inactive Tabs     */
    .nav-pills>li>a {
      background-color: #777;
      border-color: #FFFFFF;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Change color for tabs</h1>
    <hr>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 3</h3>
        <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Example :

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
      .nav-tabs{
  background-color:#161616;
}
.tab-content{
    background-color:#303136;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px
}
.nav-tabs > li > a{
  border: medium none;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover{
  background-color: #303136 !important;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0;
    color:#fff;
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```